# View mode template for user-profile.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, users, entities

I can set up a view mode for the user profile, but I don't know how to create a template targeting it. user-profile.tpl.php is the template used, but I can't figure out how to make a view-mode targeted version of it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does devel_themer tell you? http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer Also, is there any reason you can't use display suite to achieve what you're trying to do with view modes instead of .tpl.php files?

Answer (score 3):

You already figured out how to create an additional view mode for the user entity:

```
/**
 * Implements hook entity info alter
 * Adds additional view mode for user entity
 */
function MYCUSTOMMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['user']['view modes']['teaser'] = array(
      'label' => t('Teaser'),
      'custom settings' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

Now you can define theme suggestions for that view mode using HOOK_preprocess_user_profile:

```
/**
* Implements HOOK_preprocess_user_profile()
* Adds theme suggestions for the user view mode teaser
*/
function MYCUSTOMMODULE_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__teaser';
  }
```

After clearing the caches Drupal will search in the theme folder for a file called user-profile--teaser.tpl.php, which could look like this example*:

```
<section class="user-teaser">
  <?php print render($user_profile['field_last_name'][0]); ?>
  <div class="user-image">
    <figure><?php print render($user_profile['field_user_picture'][0]); ?></figure>
  </div>
  <div class="user-body">
    <?php print render($user_profile['field_biography']); ?>
    <?php print render($user_profile['field_birthdate']); ?>
    <?php print render($user_profile['field_nationality']); ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

(* actual code will depend on the fields you defined for the user profile)